# can not sending mail by php script

Tags: php, xampp, sendmail

I installed xampp in my windows.I have write a php code for sending mail.Here it is

```
$to="example@gmail.com";
$subject="Test mail";
$message="sany and sovon";
if(mail($to,$subject,$message))
  echo "mail sent succesfully";
else 
  echo "delivered failed"
```

My sendmail cofiguration in php.ini file is here
    [mail function]

```
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25


sendmail_from = localhost
```

I think the problem is in "sendmail_from".It needs my mail server address.where i get the address.There is a sendmail folder in xampp directory.Please help.Thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 2):

A quick google search produced this:

http://expertester.wordpress.com/2010/07/07/how-to-send-email-from-xampp-php/

Comment: That does not help.I want to send mail from my localhost.

Comment: Thanks,it is helpful for sending  mail by gmail